# Conditional formatting with udf issues with Office 2016 / Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a UDF that checks for the existence of a comment. I use this in CF because I want to colour a cell if 1. The cell is not blank and 2. There is no comment. This has worked just fine with 2007 and 2010 but now I have 2016 and Excel has gone a little bit weird on me.

UDF:

```
Function HasCmt(Rng As Range) 
    Application.Volatile 

    HasCmt = IIf(Not Rng.Comment Is Nothing, True, False) 

End Function
```

CF:
 =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B6)),HasCmt(B6)=FALSE)

Now when I meet the criteria, the formatting is applied and then goes away again. If I disable Automatic Calculation it behaves normally, until I recalculate. I also get errors upon saving the document. 'Calculation is incomplete...'.

Does anybody know a fix I can apply to my many workbooks I have that use this CF? Did something change in the 2016 Excel offering?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That application.volatile must be hitting the workbook pretty hard. Additionally, it doesn't seem to actually meet your two criteria so you must be using ISBLANK on top of it. Beyond the 2016 issue, have you considered any other (more efficient) methods? Strictly speaking, the .volatile does nothing to actually change the status of a cell when it receives a comment; it is only when something within the workbook changes that ALL cells are re-evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. I can't think of an alternative way to achieve this, especially since with 07 and 2010 it just 'worked'

Comment: I removed the application.volatile from the UDF and changed the logic to `If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then HasCmt = CBool(Not rng.Comment Is Nothing)`. With calculation set to automatic, the UDF performed as expected in a CF rule. This was in Excel 2013. I'll try to check on excel 2016 a little later.

Comment: Hello again Jeeped, thank you for your solution. I am having trouble with the CF rule. Should I be simply using =HasCmt=TRUE? This does not seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: I played with this for quite some time last weekend and came up with the facts that a) application.volatile is not need since CF rules reevaluate on the calculation cycle anyways; volatile makes them run on top of themselves b) volatile functions on the worksheet (today(), now(), randbetween(), offset(), indirect(), etc) were the cause of the CF not functioning properly. I have not reached a satisfactory resolution yet. I was trying to isolate the commented cells with SpecialCells when I got caught up with something else.

Comment: Just how important is the commented cell highlighting to your project and how much code are you willing to add in order to make it reliable?

Comment: Ok Jeeped, appreciate your effort to find a solution. Let me know if/when you have something that might work

Comment: I have a team of people who are used to this functionality. It is for a production schedule where the qty to build is in the cell and the work order # is in the comment. So I need it to highlight if there is a qty to be scheduled (not a blank cell) and no comment (work order). I need to replicate this functionality now we have 2016. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that any volatile functions in the workbook (or any workbook within the application instance) were generating repeated calculation event calls and the UDF was running on top of itself. Conditional formatting is 'refreshed' on every calculation cycle much as a volatile function is. Using the [Application.Volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx) method within the UDF itself was further complicating matters.

I wrote several versions of a modified UDF and once I got a stable version, I stripped back the overhead until I had the bare minimum that worked well.

```
Option Explicit

Function hasComment(rng As Range) As Boolean
    'reports true for non-blank with a comment
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then _
        hasComment = CBool(Not rng.Comment Is Nothing)
    DoEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function

Function hasNoComment(rng As Range) As Boolean
    'reports true for non-blank with no comment
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then _
        hasNoComment = Not CBool(Not rng.Comment Is Nothing)
    DoEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

Essentially, the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) is temporarily suspended. This restricts volatile functions from retriggering calculation  events. The [DoEvents function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262728.aspx) temporarily suspends reiterative execution and allows the application message queue to catch up.

This works well as the primary function within a conditional formatting rule covering several hundred cells on a worksheet containing a few hundred volatile functions.

Comment: This looks awesome but for some reason it did not format my cells. I even tried a fresh WB. I added your UDFs to a new module and my CF is =hasNoComment(B2)

Comment: I can mail you the WB I have if you wish or is there something else preventing this from functioning correctly? Thanks

Comment: my bad. When I augmented the first (tested) function with a second to reduce functions I neglected to change `hasComment = ...` to `hasNoComment = ...`.

Comment: It ms to work except when I add a comment to a non-blank cell, the formatting is still there, until I go into the CF formula and click OK>OK

Comment: Please see my notes above. The CF rules refresh on a calculation cycle just as volatile functions do.This is why making a UDF that is intended to be used in a CF rule volatile makes it run on top of itself. The situation is made worse when a volatile function like TODAY() is used on the worksheet. Yes, the responses are not immediate but they will refresh during any calculation cycle. Put a **single** `=TODAY()` anywhere in the workbook (yes, workBOOK, not necessarily workSHEET) and see if that speeds up the response.